# ZOTAC ZBOX ID18 Ubuntu install problems

Tags: system-installation, 16.04

I have this device as per the title, trying to install the latest 16.04.
The installation stops in the middle.
I dont have much experience with Ubuntu, am I using the right version for ZOTAC?. The partitions on device don't make much sense to me. Maybe it's not big enough? Its getting stuck on this:

```
Retrieving file 60 of 60
"May 20 07:24:27 ubuntu in-target: Get:60 http://au.archive.ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [160 B]"
```

I am stuck, please help.

Comment: Welcome at AskUbuntu. Can you please add a link to the specifications of your Zbox? Of course we could google them ourselves, but providing this kind of basic information will make the lives of the people who want to help you a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

I am finding the same error on a Dell inspiron 3000. Currently trying to dual boot with Windows 10 using uefi. I'll let you know if I find a workaround.

Edit**
I found this error didn't happen if you uncheck the options to download updates and restricted extras. Hopefully it works for you also.

I also find that uefi doesn't give me the option to boot into linux. So I choose "legacy" from the bios to install ubuntu, and then also choose it from the bios when I want to use ubuntu. I'm sure it's not the recommended way to get dual boot happening, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my very standard desktop pc.(i5 3570k on Gigabyte Z77 motherboard using the cpu integrated graphics with a usb wifi dongle). I tried ensuring that the updates and extras options were not selected, then changing the default server, both without success. The answer for me was to install without any internet connection. I then updated after reboot without problems.  Hope this helps.